# Extension of normal form when doing surface integrals

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

If we have a surface having a position vector parameterized $R$ by two variables $u,v$, we can find it's tangent vectors $\partial_u R ,\partial_v R$ by taking derivative of the position vector with each variable. After finding the tangent vectors, we can correspond them to the tangent one forms $r_u$ and $r_v$. Using this, we can find the normal two form as:

$$ n= \frac{r_u \wedge r_v}{|r_u \wedge r_v| }= n_3 dx \wedge dy + n_1 dy \wedge dz + n_2 dz \wedge dx$$

Now suppose we integrate the above across the surface and used stokes:

$$ \int_{\partial \omega} n = \int_{\omega} dn$$

Does applying stokes here even make sense? Because I derived $n$ from the tangent forms, hence it was a thing which existed on the surface, strictly speaking, **the components of $n$ is defined only on the surface itself. What theorem tells us that it extends, and is the extension unique?**

Comment: The $2$-form itself is dependent only on the surface, not on the parametrization, but your notation is incorrect/confusing. If $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ are the component of the unit normal vector field, then the area $2$-form of the surface is $$\sigma = n_1\,dy\wedge dz + n_2\,dz\wedge dx + n_3\,dx\wedge dy.$$ If your surface is a boundary *and* if you realize that $n_j$ are functions of $x,y,z$ so that you can write $\sigma$ as a $2$-form defined everywhere on the three-dimensional region, then, yes, it'll make sense. But stop thinking about parametrizations; with forms they are not needed.

Comment: Hi Ted, that's about what I was looking for.. but I am still a bit confused. Does $n$ have any meaning then? The original had a sort of geometry underlying it, I can't imagine it when taking a random point in the surafce @TedShifrin

Comment: It is precisely the geometry of the unit normal, but you got the formula twisted around. You can find clear derivations of these things in my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile).

Comment: In the space inside the surface, what does it mean to have a normal? We have no surface area to be normal to if that makes sense

Comment: It seems you're assuming from the start the surface is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and not just an arbitrary 2-manifold?

Comment: Yes, this is a surface in $\Bbb R^3$. The geometric origin of the $2$-form on the surface is the normal vector. I never said that geometric meaning had an extension; I merely stated that if you have a formula in $x,y,z$ that extends, then you can use that. You have to be careful. If, for example, you use $\vec n = \vec x/\|\vec x\|$ as the unit normal on a sphere centered at the origin, this will not give a $2$-form that extends to the ball; but if the sphere has radius $a$ and you use $\vec n = (1/a)\vec x$, then this will give you a fine $2$-form that extends.

Comment: Yes @aschepler that's right

Comment: I guess that's the answer. Could you write it as one? I would appreciate a reference which discusses this so I can look more into it